# ¿Que pasa cuando presiono F12 en el navegador, se ejecuta algo por detrás?

Tags: javascript, html, css, map

Perdón si no entienden bien mi pregunta pero tengo un problema un poco raro.
Estoy haciendo un imagemap, varias areas de la imagen son clickeables tienen informacion. El problema es que cada que entro a la pagina esas areas no se cargan, solo cuando doy f12 o insepccionar elemento en el navegador y se abre la consola es como funciona, pero no hago ningun cambio, simplemente al presionar f12 ya se desbloquea el contenido, alguien sabe porque podría ser?
Al revisar a fondo el codigo en ejecución note que las coordenas del mapa estan en (0,0,0,0) y cuando entro a inspeccionar elemento se cargan automáticamente.
Alguien sabe a que se debe el problema?

Aquí está mi código:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B83wvTzjUtYccVU5NWQ1WHB5V3c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: has probado en varios navegadores?

Comment: En Chrome, firefox y explorer nada más y pasa lo mismo

Comment: podrías compartir tu código para revisar qué anda ejecutando?

Comment: Claro, lo subo a google drive, dropbox o en donde?

Comment: Aqui esta mi codigo https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B83wvTzjUtYccVU5NWQ1WHB5V3c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Si, gracias. Pero como tal no hay un error especifico que yo haya encontrado por eso mejor subi el proyecto. Presiona F12 cuando lo abras y veras que ya se habilita las zonas clickleables del mapa. Me podrias ayudar?

Comment: Se cargan las coordenadas al redimensionar el navegador, por eso cuando presionas F12 funciona, se abre el recuadro con las opciones del desarrollador y cambia el tamaño de la ventana del navegador. Lo que no se es por qué las coordenadas se ponen a cero al arrancar, supongo que será el plugin _rwdImageMaps_ pero no debería hacer eso

Comment: Es verdad ya cheque eso, en sí antes no lo hacia, tengo una versión anterior del mapa donde no tenia ese preloader y funcionaba todo correctamente, ya cuando puse el preloader fue cuando dio ese problema pero como tal no veo el error @blonfu.
Checa esto en el CSS
`body > .inner {
  display: none;
}

body.pg-loaded > .inner {
  display: block;
}
`
Si borras eso del CSS ya cargan las zonas sin redimenzionar pero salen como movidas no como deberian de estar y con ese codigo quedan normales pero hay que redimenzionar para que cargen

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me conocía el truco, yo abría la consola con `control+shift+j`, pero esto es más fácil.

Answer (score 2):

F12 no ejecuta nada por si mismo, pero si el panel que abre no es flotante va a cambiar el tamaño de tu pantalla y eso dispara eventos que pueden tener efecto en tu código javascript.

Esto puedes comprobarlo redimencionando la ventana tu mismo o bien cambiando el modo del panel de herramientas a flotante.

Tal ves esto no resuelva tu problema pero creo que responde a tu pregunta:

"¿Que pasa cuando presiono F12 en el navegador, se ejecuta algo por detrás?"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes verificar aquí [KeyCodigo](https://luiscauro.github.io/KeyCodigo/), que al pulsar **F12** no sucede nada en el navegador.

Ahora, con tu problema sobre la carga de las coordenadas puede ser que el código no se está cargando al estar lista tu página. Prueba ejecutar el código dentro del evento [onLoad](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) y si aún así no se logra dentro del mismo `onLoad` usa un `setTimeout` para retardarlo aún más. Si usas librerías, ve el orden como las estás cargando.